# Access Typescript object property based on template argument

Tags: typescript, templates

I want to create a Typescript Collection class that finds items by field, something like this:

```
class Collection<T, K keyof T> {
    private _items: T[];

    public isItemInCollection(item: T) {
        return _items.find((a) => a[K] === item[K], this._items) !== undefined;
    }
 }
```

I then want to instantiate it with something like this:

```
interface MyItem {
    idField: string,
    otherField: number,
}

class ItemCollection: MyCollection<MyItem, 'idField'> { }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, I get an error on the like that references `item[K]` saying the K is a type and not a value. I understand what causes the error, I just don't know how I can fix that. Is that even possible in Typescript?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to pass a value of type `K` in somewhere at runtime for this to work.  If I understand the point of your `Collection` class properly, you will need both an actual array of `T` and a value of type `K`.  A great place to get those values is when you construct a new `Collection` instance.  That is, make the constructor take those as parameters:

```
class Collection<T, K extends keyof T> {
  private _items: T[];
  private _idKey: K;
  constructor(items: T[], idKey: K) {
    this._items = items;
    this._idKey = idKey;
  }

  public isItemInCollection(item: T) {
    return (
      this._items.find(a => a[this._idKey] === item[this._idKey]) !== undefined
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can use it as you expect (I think so, anyway... you didn't actually show your use case).  Given these types and objects:

```
interface MyItem {
  idField: string;
  otherField: number;
}
const itemA: MyItem = { idField: "A", otherField: 1 };
const itemB: MyItem = { idField: "B", otherField: 2 };
const itemC: MyItem = { idField: "C", otherField: 3 };

const items: MyItem[] = [itemA, itemB];
```

You can construct a new `Collection`:

```
const itemCollection = new Collection(items, "idField");
```

By type inference, `itemCollection` is of type `Collection<MyItem, "idField">`.  And use it:

```
console.log(itemCollection.isItemInCollection(itemA)); // true
console.log(itemCollection.isItemInCollection(itemC)); // false
console.log(
  itemCollection.isItemInCollection({ idField: "A", otherField: 2893 })
); // true so be careful
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2IQFNgBcCW8B2AeAKgDTQDS0yAHmstgCYwDWyAnvAGbT4B80A3gFDRoABwBOGAG5hq0APoZqAWwgAuTgG0AugG5BI8VJnzaJFmpK6hwHBDSiAruniiAFAuTK1+LcQwmzpACUfHpCaAAWGBAAdPJKMAC80O7KlkLQEVGxfqbM0Ek5LGkAvvx6wvYARiAYwMkQAJJKDdgISKiYOG5KXsEC6dCiyGj2otjQLqHpmTFxHjFsGHQuYPk8YOoz2f7MmvkJBUqbkbOFu8EAhAfQ9nTIi9jItFOBJfyl-EvUomxgwMjQACyzCaHhCQj8ADEMMgQLQ1LZxNgAOZpeARZCiaGw+HQbD2RSVTG6UrWbC2ZJKACCamBoMU+T4yVo2LhagARFT2cR0eFMazcQBGaDFXRkikpABCtJBSkZvGZAo5ku50F5-JhbOgACYRWKbGhKR5YDL6fLFZrcezYKr1VjLWoAMx6sriw0pVRA2UeLSM9QpKm+JSSnSug1GxRtFDoLDjJKPADucEQ0c62G682I7KhlvZrzD5MQyGiIHgyIzkZTHVj0Si9JaUerXQDgVe0AA9O2Mg5kPxxUWS2WK42Yzha41mq0q6P0ylYK3tB2u78QBBe-2UIPy3o59O0+P61P2jOXAqcziOVyeRj7RedQAOACczuKgX4bc73fsAIg8GgROgYAwCGNh7BAfggA)

Comment: Thanks, In this case I don't really need K, I can just pass `idKey: keyof T` to the constructor. I was hoping to define a collection type with Collection<MyItem, 'id'>, and then create instances.